# Python: how to schedule a task to happen after 1 hour?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a user registration that requires an activation code. I want the activation code to expire after 1 hour, so I did this:

```
def register(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateUserForm(request.data)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = get_user_model()
            user = user_manager.create_user(email=email, password=password)

            # Generate an activation code and store it in the database
            code = generate_activation_code()
            # activation = Activations.objects.create(user=12, code=code)

            # Schedule the activation code for deletion after 1 hour
            schedule_activation_code_deletion(user, code)
            # schedule_activation_code_deletion(user, code)

            # Send the activation code to the user's email address
            subject = "Your verification code"
            message = f"Your verification code is {code}"
            send_email(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, email)
            return Response('User created.')
    return Response(status=400)

def schedule_activation_code_deletion(user_id, code):
    queue = django_rq.get_queue('default')
    queue.enqueue_in(datetime.timedelta(minutes=1), test)
```

With this code I get `Error while reading from localhost:5432 : (10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)`
Is there any other library that works?

Comment: Where does this error happen, and how do you trigger the `schedule_activation_code_deletion`?

Comment: it happens when i ran the url api/register in django